# Regex: String.split and Pattern.matches does not agree with each other

Tags: java, regex

I'm practicing my regex lookarounds and, to do so, I'm trying to extract the table name from an SQL insert statement. I have the regex `(?<=INSERT INTO )\w+(?= (\(|VALUES).+)` and I'm testing it on the String `INSERT INTO tests VALUES (regex, test)`. While I'm aware that my regex isn't meticulously done, I expect it to match the `tests` substring of my input.

I'm using Java's regex engine and I'm printing out the results of what happens when I `String.split` on a regex and when I `Pattern.matches` on a regex. I get the following, seemingly-contradicting results

```
regex> (?<=INSERT INTO )\w+(?= (\(|VALUES).+)
string> INSERT INTO tests VALUES (regex, test)
[INSERT INTO ,  VALUES (regex, test)]
regex> (?<=INSERT INTO )\w+(?= (\(|VALUES).+)
string> INSERT INTO tests VALUES (regex, test)
false
```

Now just to get this on the record, the code that produced the first result is

```
Arrays.toString(searchString.split(regex))
```

while the second one came from

```
Pattern.matches(regex, searchString)
```

Isn't it that `split` splits a string on the matches to its argument? That means that the regex matched `tests` hence the result `[INSERT INTO ,  VALUES (regex, test)]`. So, why did `Pattern.matches` return false? Anything I missed?

Comment: Is `Pattern.matches` not used to match the entire string ? In your case the lookarounds are not really 'matching', but testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add a little bit to Joanna's answer: Lookaheads and lookbehinds don't participate in the match. `Pattern.matches` requires that the regex match starting at the beginning of the string going all the way to the end. Since you have a positive lookbehind (`INSERT INTO`), the match starts at `text` which is not at the beginning. Likewise, the lookahead at the end means there is no match at the end either.

`split` works as expected because it doesn't require the match to start at the beginning.

Answer (score 4):

I would try if you get the same problem if you use:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(yourRegex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
```

and check if `m.find()` returns true

`Pattern.matches` expects the whole string to match - it might have a problem with the lookarounds as these are zero-width assertions and as such the matched characters are discarded.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I found alan's more informative. (--,)